# Problem with the use of Binary Map Data Structure in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I want to create an **ordered map** with multiples nodes in SML . All i have found until now , exist here : https://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/binary-map-fn.html . So , i am trying something like this :

```
structure S = BinaryMapFn(struct
    type ord_key = int
    val compare = Int.compare
  end);
```

and then , i am trying to insert for example 2 nodes with value 0 and key values 1 and 2 , respectively :

```
S.insert(S.empty,1,0);
S.insert(S.empty,2,0);
```

output:val it = T {cnt=1,key=2,left=E,right=E,value=0} : int S.map

```
S.numItems(it);
```

output:val it = 1 : int

So, i am assuming by the output of numItems that it creates 2 binary maps with 1 node each and not a single one . I am pretty sure i am missing something , but there is not enough material and examples related to that structure .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to look at is the type of the [insert](https://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/ord-map.html#SIG:ORD_MAP.insert:VAL) function, as well as [empty](https://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/ord-map.html#SIG:ORD_MAP.empty:VAL) in the signature [ORD_MAP](https://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/ord-map.html) to which BinaryMapFn conforms.

```
val empty : 'a map 
val insert : ('a map * Key.ord_key * 'a) -> 'a map
```

So, insert takes a (fromMap, key, x) and returns a new map which contains the elements of *fromMap* with x/key added as well with duplicate keys handled in some fashion.

To get a map with 2 elements, rather than using S.empty in both calls, you need to pass the return value of the first call as a parameter to the second.

**note**: It is worth noting that the smlnj-lib documentation is very old, and
   out of date, but i'm unaware of a newer link, so it is best to
   consult the source.